# In a acute angled triangle, we have $\tan(A)\cdot\tan(B)\cdot\tan(C) \geq 3\sqrt{3}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality, geometric-inequalities

How to show:

> In a acute angled $\triangle  \ ABC$ show that $$\tan(A) \cdot \tan(B)\cdot \tan(C) \geq 3\sqrt{3}$$

Any ideas?

Comment: Use $\tan A \cdot \tan B \cdot \tan C = \tan A + \tan B + \tan C$, and the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: The question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8732/how-to-prove-this-trignometrical-identities includes the identity Srivatsan mentions.

Answer (score 4):

These may be useful:

- Since $\triangle ABC$ is acute, we have $\tan(A),\tan(B),\tan(C)$ positive.
- By [A.M-G.M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) you have $$\displaystyle \frac{\tan(A)+\tan(B)+\tan(C)}{3} \geq \sqrt[3]{\tan(A)\cdot\tan(B)\cdot\tan(C)}$$
- $\text{The equality holds if the triangle is}$ $\textbf{equilateral.}$

Answer (score 1):

$$A+B=\pi-C$$

> \begin{align*}
> &\tan  (A+B)= \tan  (\pi-C)\\
> &(\tan  A+ \tan  B)/(1-\tan  A \tan B)= (\tan  \pi- \tan  C)/(1+\tan  \pi \tan  C)=-\tan C\\
> &(\tan  A+ \tan  B)= -\tan  C(1-\tan  A \tan  B)\\
> &\tan  A + \tan  B= -\tan  C+ \tan  A \tan  B \tan  C\\
> &\tan  A + \tan  B+ \tan  C= \tan  A \tan  B \tan  C
> \end{align*}

Comment: Now u can use the am-gm inequality as others have stated. and no problem in using that inequality as all the variables involved iwll be positive quantities in case of an acute angled traingle

Comment: You mean $A+B=\pi - C$, I guess. It would also be good if you indicated where exactly you need to use that $A,B,C \lt \pi/2$.

Comment: $A+B+C=\pi$, not $2\pi$.  Fortunately, $\tan(\pi)=\tan(2\pi)$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Use the AM-GM inequality.