# Prove that $\tan\alpha\tan\beta\tan\gamma > 1$, where $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are angles in an acute triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Needed to prove that

> $$\tan \alpha \cdot \tan \beta \cdot \tan \gamma > 1$$
> where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma < 90^\circ$ (parts of an acute triangle).

This question came up during a lesson and the teacher couldn't prove it with the methods we have.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["In a acute angled triangle, we have $\tan(A)\cdot \tan(B)\cdot \tan(C)\geq 3\sqrt{3}$"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57178/409).

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\sum_{\alpha, \beta,\gamma} \tan \alpha=\prod_{\alpha, \beta,\gamma} \tan \alpha$ for angles of a triangle.

Now, all three angles of an acute angled triangle cannot be less than $45°$. Hence, $\sum_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma} \tan \alpha$ must be more than $1$, hence the product too.