# Area of the triangle a,b,c

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

How to prove in any triangle that the area $X$ is given by:

$$X=\frac{1}{4}(a+b+c)^2\tan \frac{A}{2} \tan \frac{B}{2} \tan \frac{C}{2}$$

Comment: There is a hint for the product of the $\tan '$s:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477364/prove-that-tan-a-tan-b-tan-c-tan-a-tan-b-tan-c-abc-180-circ

Comment: It isn't a hint ... It's better -> $\tan \frac{A}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{(s-b)(s-c)}{s(s-a)}}$

Comment: Is this better?: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula. Look at the "Proof using the Law of cotangents and the triple cotangent identity" paragraph.

Comment: Yes, it's a hint now -.-

Answer (score 1):

assume that c is the longest side and that d is perpendicular to c forming 2 right triangles.  The angle between a and d should be called D. The line along c from a to d is c'.

$$Area=\frac 14(a+b+c)^2\tan\frac{A}{2}\tan\frac{B}{2}\tan\frac{C}{2}$$
$$Area=\frac 14(a+c'+d)^2\tan\frac{D}{2}\tan\frac{B}{2}\tan45+\frac 14(b+d+c-c')^2\tan\frac{A}{2}\tan\frac{C-D}{2}\tan45$$
$$\tan 45=1$$
$$d^2=a^2-c'^2=b^2-(c-c')^2$$
IFF we can show the following that works, then the full one should too!
$$\frac 14(a+c'+d)^2\tan\frac{D}{2}\tan\frac{B}{2}=\frac 12c'd$$
$$B=90-D$$
$$\tan \frac B2 = \frac{\sin B}{1+\cos B}$$
$$\tan \frac D2 = \frac{\sin D}{1+\cos D}$$
$$\sin B = \cos D = \frac da$$
$$\sin D = \cos B = \frac {c'}a$$
$$\tan\frac{D}{2}\tan\frac{B}{2} = \frac{c'd}{a^2+ac'+ad+c'd}$$
$$\frac 14(a+c'+d)^2\frac{c'd}{a^2+ac'+ad+c'd}=\frac 12c'd$$
$$(a+c'+d)^2=2(a^2+ac'+ad+c'd)$$
$$a^2+c'^2+d^2+2ac'+2ad+2c'd=2a^2+2ac'+2ad+2c'd$$
$$a^2+c'^2+d^2=2a^2$$
$$c'^2+d^2=a^2$$
which is true.... if we repeat for the other right triangle this works.... Doing it from the Heron is easier but only, I guess, if you know the Heron and can prove it.This uses http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula so .... yeah....

Comment: Do you know about where can I find the demonstration of this formula ?

Comment: I guess http://math.ucsd.edu/~wgarner/math4c/textbook/chapter6/doublehalfangles.htm but I used it because it is the only half angle formula I know off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Use the popular identity: $$\tan\left(\frac A2\right)\tan\left(\frac B2\right)\tan\left(\frac C2\right) = \frac rp$$
$$RHS = \frac{1}{4}\times 4p^2*\frac rp = pr = A = LHS$$

Comment: And you know that these equalities hold because????

Comment: of the laws of sine and cosine and Heron formula ?

Comment: That is completely uninformative.

Comment: it can be derived using different ways....

Comment: Well, show us one of them, then.

Comment: When you say "popular identity", what do you mean? If you mean "the one the cool kids know", that may be true (for some definition of "cool"), but the OP is then not a cool kid, so explain to him/her and the rest of us.

Comment: @IgorRivin It's enough $tan(\frac A2)tan(\frac B2)tan(\frac C2) = \frac rp$ to prove.

Comment: So I can do a demo on A = pr. So let AB = c, BC = a, and CA = b, then A = 1/2*ar + 1/2*br + 1/2*cr = 1/2(2p)r = pr.

Comment: @Ewin what is it with you guys? If the OP knew this, do you think he would ask?

Comment: (tan(A/2)tan(B/2)tan(C/2))^2 = ((p-b)(p-c)/p(p-a))*((p-a)(p-c)/p(p-b))*((p-a)(p-b)/p(p-c))= (p-a)(p-b)(p-c)/p^3 = (A^2/p)/p^3 = A^2/p^4 = (pr)^2/p^4 = r^2/p^2. So taking square root we get the identity above.

Comment: I enjoy the discussion.

Comment: @Ewin weather forecast?

Answer (score -1):

From [this](http://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-properties-and-solutions-of-triangles/solution-of-triangles/), $$\tan\frac A2=\sqrt{\frac{(s-b)(s-c)}{s(s-a)}}\text{  where  } s=\frac{a+b+c}2$$

This can be easily derived using [Tangent half-angle formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) and the [Law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)

Now we know [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)

Comment: @Ewin, how about this?