# Evaluate $\tan\frac{\pi}{7}\tan\frac{2\pi}{7}\tan\frac{3\pi}{7}=\sqrt 7$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to show that

> $$\tan\frac{\pi}{7}\tan\frac{2\pi}{7}\tan\frac{3\pi}{7}=\sqrt 7$$

My attempt:
Since $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} $ so immediately the denominator is recognized as $$\prod_{k=1}^{3}\cos\frac{k\pi}{7}=\frac{1}{2^3}=\frac{1}{8}$$ as known since elementary classes. To tackle with sine product I tried as $\sin(x)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)$. But I fail with this ideas.

How do  I deal with $\sin x$ product?

Comment: The product runs from  1 to 3 not 1 to 4 .

Comment: Thanks,I have fixed it.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1928997/show-that-tan-pi-7-tan2-pi-7-tan3-pi-7-sqrt7

Comment: [AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h374955p2069100) also.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346368/sum-of-tangent-functions-where-arguments-are-in-specific-arithmetic-series

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351337/product-of-cosines-prod-r-17-cos-left-fracr-pi15-right) by @ Darth Geek, in general we have  $$S(n)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n+1} \right)=\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}}{2^n}$$   set $n=3$ we have $S(3)=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{8}$ and we are done. Also $$C(n)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\cos\left(\frac{k \pi}{2n+1} \right)=\frac{1}{2^n}$$.

---

**Alternative approach:**
We   exploit  reflection formula of the *gamma function* ,

$$ \Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin{\pi}{ z}}$$ giving us $$\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\sin\frac{3\pi}{7}\sin\frac{3\pi}{7}=\frac{\pi^3}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{6}{7}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{7}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{7}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{7}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)}=\frac{\sqrt 7 \pi^3}{8\pi^3 } $$ We deduce the  latter result using [multiplication theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20multiplication%20theorem,of%20values%3B%20thus%20the%20name.) for gamma function.
Now it is just simplification which gives  us $\sqrt 7$.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the $S(n)$ term?

Comment: I was aware of the general identity however, it takes me time to find the reference here in SE. I have now updated. Please have a look once. In the trigonometry book by S.L Loney we may find such numerous of identities