# In a triangle $ABC$ if $A:B:C= 1:2:4$ then value of $\tan A\tan B+\tan B\tan C+\tan C\tan A$

Tags: trigonometry

I know that I should be using the property
$$\tan A\tan B+\tan B\tan C+\tan C\tan A=1+\sec A\sec B\sec C.$$

Now I don't know how to calculate $\sec A\sec B\sec C$ without using a calculator as the angles aren't the regular ones.
 So my question is how will I be able to find the required value without using the calculator?

Comment: A:B:C is it the ratio of angles?

Comment: If A:B:C is it the ratio of angles, then $A=\frac {\pi} 7,B=2\frac {\pi} 7,C=4\frac {\pi} 7$

Comment: plug these angles in the term above

Comment: Yes it is the ratio of angles

Comment: @eugen covaci: my question was how can I calculate the numerical value myself, without using a calculator

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823819/if-alpha-frac2-pi7-then-the-find-the-value-of-tan-alpha-tan2-alpha/824178#824178

Comment: Thanks, lab bhattacharjee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT

Use the formula $cos(\frac {\pi} 7)cos(\frac {2\pi} 7)cos(\frac {3\pi} 7)=\frac 1 8$ and the fact that $cos(\frac {4\pi} 7)=-cos(\frac {3\pi} 7)$.

For a proof of the formula see [this](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-prove-cos-pi-7-cos-2pi-7-cos-3pi-7-1-8)

Also you can take a look at [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi7.html)

Comment: Any chance, you can explain the calculations because the link you gave contains mathematics that isn't in my course. I also have to find the value of sec^2(A)+sec^2(B)+sec^2(C).

Comment: @nikola See this: https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-prove-cos-pi-7-cos-2pi-7-cos-3pi-7-1-8

Comment: any chance, you also know how to find the value of sec^2(A)+sec^2(B)+sec^2(C), please.

Comment: @nikola You have to post another question

Comment: Well, thanks I think I can pick up from here.

Answer (score 1):

After knowing the angles $A=\frac{\pi}{7}$, $B=\frac{2\pi}{7}$ and $C=\frac{4\pi}{7}$

$$\tan A\tan B+\tan B\tan C+\tan C\tan A=1+\sec A\sec B\sec C.$$

Substituting angles you should get $$\tan A\tan B+\tan B\tan C+\tan C\tan A=-7$$

Comment: Could the angles be calculated using values of trigonometric functions of 30, 45 and 60 degrees, like we find the value of 36 degree

Comment: That requires trigonometric transformations,and i will try to add it

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate:

$$\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right) \cdot \cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right) \cdot \cos \left(\frac{4\pi}{7}\right)=P \quad (1)$$

We will use that

$$\sin(2x)=2\sin x \cos x \quad (2)$$

Multiply both sides of the equation $(1)$ by $\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right)$:

$$\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right) \cdot\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right) \cdot \cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right) \cdot \cos \left(\frac{4\pi}{7}\right)=P\cdot \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right)$$

Now using $(2)$ for $x=\pi/7$ we get:

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \sin \left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right) \cdot \cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right) \cdot \cos \left(\frac{4\pi}{7}\right)=P\cdot \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right)$$

Now using $(2)$ for $x=2\pi/7$ we get:

$$\frac{1}{4}\cdot \sin \left(\frac{4\pi}{7}\right) \cdot \cos \left(\frac{4\pi}{7}\right)=P\cdot \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right)$$

Now using $(2)$ for $x=4\pi/7$ we get:

$$\frac{1}{8}\cdot \sin \left(\frac{8\pi}{7}\right) =P\cdot \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right)$$

Now remember that

$$\sin \left(\frac{8\pi}{7}\right)=\sin \left(\pi+\frac{\pi}{7}\right)=-\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right)$$

then:

$$P=-\frac{1}{8}$$

and:

$$1+\sec A\cdot \sec B \cdot \sec C= 1-8=-7$$