# Simplifying $\sec^2 \frac{2\pi}{7} + \sec^2 \frac{4\pi}{7} + \sec^2 \frac{8\pi}{7}$

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

> Simplify the following expression:
>   $$y =\sec^2 \frac{2\pi}{7} + \sec^2 \frac{4\pi}{7} + \sec^2 \frac{8\pi}{7}$$

**Note.** The source asks the value of $y/3$, which, according to the instructions, has to be an integer from $0$ to $9$.

---

**My Attempt:**

Man! I tried everything I could. Converted it into sin's and cosine's, tan's and sec's. Applied every identity I could find in my book. But to no avail.

All I was aiming is to somehow make the squares disappear and converting everything in sin's and cosine's since we only know to simplify such expressions
like ($\cos x + \cos 2x + \cos 3x+\cdots$ and $\cos x\cos 2x\cos 4x\cdots$ etc) in tems of sin's and cosine's. (Sorry for all the sin's and cosine's being repeated too many times :) )

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The result is rather simple...

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175736/evaluate-tan220-circ-tan240-circ-tan280-circ/175740#175740

Comment: The result is given by $$24$$

Comment: @OlivierOloa Has to be! Because the question asked the value of $\frac{y}{3}$ which according to the instructions, has to be an integer from 0 to 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [If $\alpha = \frac{2\pi}{7}$ then the find the value of $\tan\alpha .\tan2\alpha +\tan2\alpha \tan4\alpha +\tan4\alpha \tan\alpha.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823819/if-alpha-frac2-pi7-then-the-find-the-value-of-tan-alpha-tan2-alpha/824178#824178),

the roots of 
$$t^3-21t^2+35t-7=0$$  are $\tan^2\dfrac{2n\pi}7, n=1,2,4$

Using Vieta's Formula,

$$\tan^2\dfrac{2\pi}7+\tan^2\dfrac{4\pi}7+\tan^2\dfrac{8\pi}7=\dfrac{21}1$$

Comment: So, how did you guess that this cubic ($x^3 - 21x^2 + 35x -7$) has the given roots ($\tan^2 \frac{2n\pi}{7}, n = 1,2,4$)?

Comment: @Tony, Observe from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823819/if-alpha-frac2-pi7-then-the-find-the-value-of-tan-alpha-tan2-alpha/824178#824178, the roots of $$x^6-21x^4+35x^2-7=0$$ are $\tan\dfrac{n\pi}7, n\equiv\pm1,\pm2,\pm3\pmod7$  and $$\tan(\pi\pm y)=\pm\tan y$$ So, $\tan\dfrac{8\pi}7=\tan\dfrac\pi7$