# How to prove $\tan3°\tan63°\tan69°=\tan15°$?

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove $\tan3°\tan63°\tan69°=\tan15°$

---

And assuming we don't know that $\tan15^{\circ}$ part, how to just evaluate $\tan3^{\circ} tan63^{\circ} tan69^{\circ}$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477364/prove-that-tan-a-tan-b-tan-c-tan-a-tan-b-tan-c-abc-180-circ?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$\sin3^{\circ}\sin63^{\circ}\sin69^{\circ}\cos15^{\circ}=\cos3^{\circ}\cos63^{\circ}\cos69^{\circ}\sin15^{\circ}$$ or
$$(\cos60^{\circ}-\cos66^{\circ})(\sin84^{\circ}+\sin54^{\circ})=(\cos60^{\circ}+\cos66^{\circ})(\sin84^{\circ}-\sin54^{\circ})$$ or
$$\sin84^{\circ}\cos66^{\circ}=\sin54\cos60^{\circ}$$ or
$$\sin150^{\circ}+\sin18^{\circ}=\sin54^{\circ}$$ or
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt5-1}{4}=\frac{\sqrt5+1}{4},$$
which is obvious.

Done!

Comment: Thank you for this concise proving.  What if it's just an evaluation of $\tan3^{\circ} \tan63^{\circ} \tan69^{\circ}$?  Can that be solved by a similar method?

Comment: @mo-han Yes. Why no? The value $2-\sqrt3$ would be say about a similar method.

Comment: Need more details, it's just too difficult for me to fill up the gap.  I suppose those transformation above would not be intact any more.

Answer (score 0):

Though I hate reverse engineering, I'm yet to find how the problem came being.

Here is one approach of validating the proposition:

We need $$\dfrac{\sin3^\circ\sin63^\circ}{\cos3^\circ\cos63^\circ}=\dfrac{\sin15^\circ\sin21^\circ}{\cos15^\circ\cos21^\circ}$$

Using [componendo and dividendo](http://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Junior%20Secondary/Componendo%20et%20Dividendo.htm),  $$\dfrac{\cos(63-3)^\circ}{\cos(63+3)^\circ}=\dfrac{\cos(21-15)^\circ}{\cos(21+15)^\circ}$$

$$\iff\cos36^\circ=2\cos6^\circ\cos66^\circ=\cos(66-6)^\circ+\cos(66+6)^\circ$$

which has been established here: [Proving trigonometric equation $\cos(36^\circ) - \cos(72^\circ) = 1/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827540/proving-trigonometric-equation-cos36-circ-cos72-circ-1-2)