# If $A, B, C$ are angles of $\Delta ABC$ and $\sin (A-\pi /4) \sin (B-\pi/4) \sin (C-\pi/4)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}$...

Tags: trigonometry

> If $A, B, C$ are angles of $\Delta ABC$ and $\sin (A-\pi /4) \sin (B-\pi/4) \sin (C-\pi/4)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}$, then prove that $\sum \tan A \tan B=\sum \tan A$

Solving the given equation, we get$$(\sin A-\cos A)(\sin B -\cos B)(\sin C -\cos C)=1$$
$$(\tan A-1)(\tan B-1)(\tan C-1)=\sec A \sec B \sec C$$
$$\sum \tan A -\sum \tan A \tan B +\sum \tan A-1=\sec A \sec B \sec C$$

How should I proceed?

Comment: One observation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477364/prove-that-tan-a-tan-b-tan-c-tan-a-tan-b-tan-c-abc-180-circ

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I am well aware of that. I even used it in my answer, where is equated $\tan A \tan B \tan C =\sum \tan A$

Answer (score 1):

From the given

\begin{align}0=&\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}- \sin (A-\pi /4) \sin (B-\pi/4) \sin (C-\pi/4)\\
=&\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}-\frac12\left[ \cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B-\frac\pi2)\right] \sin (C-\pi/4)\\
=&\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}[ 1- (\cos(A-B)-\sin C) (\sin C - \cos C)]
\end{align}

Note that $\cos(A-B)\le 1$ and
\begin{align}
0 \ge & \frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}[1-( 1 -\sin C ) (\sin C - \cos C)]\\
=& \frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}[(1+\cos C) - \sin C (1+\cos C - \sin C) ]\\
=& \frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}[2\cos^2 \frac C2- \sin C (2\cos^2 \frac C2 - 2\sin \frac C2\cos\frac C2)] \\
=&\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\cos^2 \frac C2\left[1- 2\sin\frac C2(\cos \frac C2 - \sin \frac C2)\right] \\
=& \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\cos^2 \frac C2(2- \sin C  - \cos C ) 
\end{align}

which leads to
$\cos\frac C2=0$, i.e.
$C = \pi$ and $A=B = 0$. Thus,

$$
\tan A\tan B+\tan B\tan C+\tan C\tan A = \tan A+\tan B+\tan C =0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Both
\begin{align} 
\sin (A-\pi /4) \sin (B-\pi/4) \sin (C-\pi/4)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

and
\begin{align} 
\tan A\tan B+\tan B\tan C+\tan C\tan A
&=
\tan A+\tan B+\tan C
,
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}

expressed in terms of semiperimeter $\rho$, 
inradius $r$ and circumradius $R$ of the triangle,
are equivalent to

\begin{align} 
\rho^2&=r^2+4\,r\,R+2\,\rho\,r
\tag{3}\label{3}
,
\end{align}

which implies

\begin{align} 
\rho&=r+\sqrt{2\,r^2+4\,r\,R}
\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

But \eqref{4} is true only for the degenerate triangle
when one angle is $180^\circ$ and the other two are zero.

For the conversion, 
use known identities for the angles of triangle

\begin{align}
\cos A\cos B\cos C&=\frac{r}{R}+1
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
\sin A\sin B\sin C
&=
\frac{\rho\,r}{2R^2}
\tag{6}\label{6}
,
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\tan A\tan B\tan C
=
\tan A+\tan B+\tan C
&=\frac{2\rho\,r}{\rho^2-(r+2\,R)^2}
\tag{7}\label{7}
,\\
\tan A\tan B+\tan B\tan C+\tan C\tan A
&=1+\frac{4\,R^2}{\rho^2-(r+2\,R)^2}
\tag{8}\label{8}
,\\
\cot A+\cot B+\cot C&=
\frac12\,\left(\frac{\rho}r
-\frac r\rho \right)
-2\,\frac R\rho
\tag{9}\label{9}
.
\end{align}

Comment: Isn’t $\sum \tan A = \tan A \tan B \tan C$? You have written $\tan A \tan B \tan C =\sum \tan A \tan B$

Comment: @Aditya: Yes, of course, in \eqref{2} 
$\sum\tan A\tan B=\sum\tan A=\prod\tan A=\frac{2\rho\,r}{\rho^2-(r+2\,R)^2}$.